# Some letters not centering in a Box

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making a custom keyboard with jetpack compose, and it seems that some letters such as the letter y are more at the bottom and are not centered, even when aligning it.

for example:

```
       Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Red),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            Text("y", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
```

the result is this:

[image]

Whears the same code with the letter l is centered properly:

[image]

can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: the y in first is the smaller case may be. try using upper case

Comment: @AgentP But I want to use the lower case

Answer (score 1):

The letters are both centred correctly. The lowercase y appears lower as that is how the letter is drawn/written (the tail of the y goes below the bottom of an uppercase I).

If you wanted to account for that, you could always apply an offset modifier to the Text Composable to shift its position upward.

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(50.dp)
        .background(Red),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(y = -16.dp),  // Choose an appropriate value
        text = "y", fontSize = 30.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there should be a logic for accounting for this, I can't just edit it manually every time for every box.

Comment: You will have to implement that logic yourself, personally I see no issue with the centering logic being performed here. Perhaps the best approach is to create a list of characters that require to be offset upwards (qpgjy) and when drawing that letter, apply the offset only then. A more complete solution may be to create a map of values to their required offset, that way you can customize each letters offset individually with ease.